# Can I make a simple trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

If I create a before insert/update trigger I know how to do something like this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE INSERT ON def_servpath_0001_weatherstation
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE someString text;
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.atrType = 'datetime' THEN
            SET someString := NEW.atrValue;
        END IF;
    END;

    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.atrType <> 'datetime' THEN
            SET NEW.atrMD = someString;
        END IF;
    END;
END;//
```

My question is, can I do something simple like:

```
 DECLARE someString varchar(100);
 SET someString = (SELECT NEW.atrValue FROM **NEW** WHERE NEW.atrType = 'datetime');

 UPDATE **NEW**
 SET NEW.atrValue = someString;
```

**EDIT**

Better split in two parts.

- Can I get the field value of a new row? Or should I have to loop for all the rows?
- Can I update all rows at once? or Should I loop for all the rows and update each one.

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
CREATE TABLE [test] ( atrType nvarchar(100), atrValue nvarchar(100), atrMD  nvarchar(100));
INSERT INTO [test] VALUES 
    ('datetime', '20150915', ''),
    ('name', 'Juan', ''),
    ('city', 'Caracas', '');

** Trigger**

SELECT * 
FROM [test]

atrType  atrValue    atrMD  
datetime 20150915    20150915
name     Juan        20150915
city     Caracas     20150915
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? it seems that you only want to update a row if it attends to a criteria but your criteria is with the same value you update! It is confusing

Comment: @JorgeCampos Correct. only one new row have `type` = 'datatime' and `value`  = 'somestring' ... i want the rest of the row also have `value`  = 'somestring'

Comment: You are trying to find out values from all the update set? Like if you run the update command and it works for 10 rows you want to check from those 10 rows? Because if that is the case you can't do it in a trigger you will have to create a function to do it

Comment: @JorgeCampos I update my question.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do. One thing that might help is that you've put in FOR EACH ROW. This means that the trigger willl be called once for each row that's inserted/updated (i.e. no matter how many rows are affected, NEW will always have 1 row in it.

Comment: Your question is related to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32391936?

Comment: @wchiquito, Yes i provide that query in another question. But I was looking if there is an easy way to do it. Looks like he couldn't make my query work because syntax. But the query logic is good. Search one value from the insert data and then update the rest of the insert data.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: ¿MySQL or MS SQL Server?. One option, MySQL, it can be [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f88fd9/1).