# After insert trigger in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a trigger in mysql that runs after insert in table. After insert it takes a value from a column attrValue where attrType equals 'datetime' and updates another column called attrMd.

This is my try for now but it keeps saying I have a syntax value in line 4:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

I can't figure it out. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks...

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE INSERT ON def_servpath_0001_weatherstation
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 DECLARE someString text;
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
     IF NEW.atrType = 'datetime' THEN
         SET @someString := NEW.atrValue;
     END IF;
 END;

 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
     IF NEW.atrType <> 'datetime' THEN
         SET NEW.atrMD = someString;
     END IF;
 END;
END;//
```

**Edit**
[image]

Comment: I wrote after insert, but it's before insert. Sorry...

Comment: Where you are running the trigger ? mysql cli / phpmyadmin ? and what exactly the the trigger is supposed to do , its pretty confusing from the given code. Please add more information on it.

Comment: I'm running it on phpmyadmin. Trigger is supposed to update column attrMd with the declared variable someString . someString takes the value from the column attrValue if the given condition is fullfilled...

Comment: still not clear how you can have `NEW.atrType = 'datetime'` and then set some value and at the same time `NEW.atrType <> 'datetime'` ? Best would be provide some sample data and expected result once the insert happens.

Comment: I'll post an image of what I'm trying to do...

Comment: i posted the image for a better look...

Comment: Your question is related to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32358431?

Answer (score 0):

Some points to consider:

- Remember to change the `DELIMITER` option in phpMyAdmin.
- It is important to indicate the difference between [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) (`@someString`) and local variables [13.6.4.1 Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html) (`someString`), are different variables.
- It has some more instructions (`FOR EACH ROW`).

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE INSERT ON def_servpath_0001_weatherstation
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 DECLARE someString text;
 -- FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
     IF NEW.atrType = 'datetime' THEN
         SET @someString := NEW.atrValue;
     END IF;
 END;

 -- FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
     IF NEW.atrType <> 'datetime' THEN
         SET NEW.atrMD = someString;
     END IF;
 END;
END;//
```

Comment: thanks for the heads up, it got through, but it isn't working properly, I'll post an image what it's supposed to do...

Comment: I use two `for each row` because not sure if `atrType = 'datetime'`is always the first one.

Comment: The syntax does not allow this structure (two `FOR EACH ROW`). See [13.1.19 CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html).