# Find missing dates in a month of april in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

I'm almost new in mysql and trying to solve this query. I have two tables

one is month_april and second is month_sales

**Month_april** table

```
Month_dates             

2015-04-01            
2015-04-02
2015-04-03
2015-04-04
2015-04-05
2015-04-06

  .
  .
  .
  .

2015-04-30
```

**Month_sales** table

```
Month_dates    Sale_name
2015-04-01     Remote
2015-04-05     Remote
2015-04-08     Remote
2015-04-09     Remote
2015-04-10     Remote
2015-04-15     Remote
2015-04-20     Remote
2015-04-25     Remote
2015-04-30     Remote
```

These are two tables and there is one product only name "Remote". I need data of the missing dates of "Month_sales" table with "Sale_name"

Is that possible to get data using month_sales table only ? If no then how I can get using both tables.

I'm looking for output like this

```
Month_dates   Sale_name

2015-04-02     Remote
2015-04-03     Remote 
2015-04-04     Remote 
2015-04-06     Remote 
2015-04-07     Remote 
2015-04-11     Remote 
2015-04-12     Remote        
2015-04-13     Remote 
2015-04-14     Remote 
2015-04-16     Remote 
2015-04-17     Remote 
2015-04-18     Remote 
2015-04-19     Remote         
2015-04-21     Remote 
2015-04-22     Remote 
2015-04-23     Remote 
2015-04-24     Remote 
2015-04-26     Remote
2015-04-27     Remote
2015-04-28     Remote
2015-04-29     Remote
```

Comment: have a table that goes back years, forward years, like you did with month_april, just don't call it that

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select ma.month_date, 'Remote' as sale_name
from month_april ma left join
     month_sales ms
     on ma.month_date = ms.month_date
where ms.month_date is null;
```

Comment: Hello Gordon. If you have time can take a look to my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32358431/can-i-make-a-simple-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

You can `left join` on the dates table to find the missing dates.

```
select a.month_dates, s.sales_name
from month_april a
left join month_sales s 
on a.month_dates <> s.month_dates
where s.month_dates is not null;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89817/3)